# MySQL trigger before Insert value Checking

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table `staff` with `office` column. Currently the `office` column do not accept NULL values. The application persisting onto this table has a bug which meant that, when the staff has not been assigned an office, it tries inserting a NULL value onto the table.

I have been asked to used a trigger to intercept the insert onto the `Staff` table and check if the `office` value is NULL and replace it with value `N/A`.

Below is my attempt so far, but do have `error` in attempt to implement. Any Ideas on how to resolve this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER staffOfficeNullReplacerTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON Staff
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.office IS NULL)
     INSERT INTO Staff SET office="N/A";
    END IF
  END;
```

**The error:**

> MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Staff SET office="N/A"; END'

Comment: Why not change the schema so that `NULL` values are permitted?  This is exactly what `NULL` should be used for, as it enables one to differentiate between no office and an office which happens to have the value of `N/A` (whereas your proposed solution would not).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, alter the table to allow NULLs:

```
ALTER TABLE Staff MODIFY office CHAR(40) DEFAULT "N/A";
```

(Change `CHAR(40)` to whatever is appropriate.) Then you could use as your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER staffOfficeNullReplacerTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON Staff
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.office IS NULL) THEN
      SET NEW.office = "N/A";
    END IF
```

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER staffOfficeNullReplacerTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON Staff
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF (NEW.office IS NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO Staff(office) VALUES("N/A");
   END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER staffOfficeNullReplacerTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON Staff
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.office IS NULL)
     INSERT INTO Staff SET office="N/A";
    END IF
```

> ; add semi colon after END IF

```
  END;
```