# add column with range limit , values of that column must not be specific values

Tags: mysql

Write the code in mysql that add column color (varchar(20)) in table boats, default value is 'pink' , values in that column that are not allowed are : 'white','black', 'red'( other values are allowed !! )

ALTER TABLE Boats
add column color varchar(20) default 'pink' ... ?

Comment: Though poorly expressed, this sounds like a problem involving CHECK CONSTRAINTS, which MySQL doesn't support, so I wonder if you've used the correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is correct but as `color` data type `varchar` you can add anything into it. You have to manage those checks in your programming language.

You can use `Trigger` to restrict input. Here is an example:

[MySQL trigger before Insert value Checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836270/mysql-trigger-before-insert-value-checking)

To restrict the inputs you can use `ENUM` but it will allow you to enter only specific values which you defined into `ENUM` into database

Here is the documentation link:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: ENUM has only possible values for that column, my question is for a column that must not  have those values such as white , black, red  .
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @yh264 then you have to use triggers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836270/mysql-trigger-before-insert-value-checking